# go test fails when providing -coverpkg parameter

Tags: go, testing, code-coverage, go-testing

I'm trying to get the test coverage across all packages in my project.

tests are getting executed successfully and report the coverage when I execute the following command.

```sh
go test -cover ./...
```

but all the tests are failing when I execute `go test` with `coverpkg=./...` parameter

```sh
go test -cover -coverpkg=./... ./...
```

This is the sample output of the command

```
srimal@srimal-pc:~/projects/myproject$ go test -v -cover -coverpkg=./... ./...
go build a.abc.com/path/to/module/e2e: no non-test Go files in /home/srimal/projects/driver-selection-handler/e2e
?       a.abc.com/path/to/module      [no test files]
?       a.abc.com/path/to/module/app  [no test files]
?       a.abc.com/path/to/module/constrain    [no test files]
FAIL    a.abc.com/path/to/module/directionalhire [build failed]
?       a.abc.com/path/to/module/domain       [no test files]
FAIL    a.abc.com/path/to/module/durationmatrix [build failed]
FAIL    a.abc.com/path/to/module/durationmatrix/etaservice [build failed]
FAIL    a.abc.com/path/to/module/durationmatrix/roadmatrix [build failed]
2021/04/22 17:23:07 go-util/log: Cannot open config file  open config/logger.yaml: no such file or directory
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
coverage: 0.0% of statements in ./...
ok      a.abc.com/path/to/module/e2e  (cached)        coverage: 0.0% of statements in ./... [no tests to run]
?       a.abc.com/path/to/module/events       [no test files]
FAIL    a.abc.com/path/to/module/finance [build failed]
?       a.abc.com/path/to/module/internal     [no test files]
?       a.abc.com/path/to/module/internal/config      [no test files]
?       a.abc.com/path/to/module/internal/logger      [no test files]
?       a.abc.com/path/to/module/internal/metrics     [no test files]
?       a.abc.com/path/to/module/internal/profiling   [no test files]
?       a.abc.com/path/to/module/internal/schema      [no test files]
?       a.abc.com/path/to/module/internal/stream      [no test files]
FAIL    a.abc.com/path/to/module/location [build failed]
?       a.abc.com/path/to/module/logger       [no test files]
?       a.abc.com/path/to/module/metrics      [no test files]
FAIL    a.abc.com/path/to/module/selection [build failed]
FAIL    a.abc.com/path/to/module/store [build failed]
FAIL    a.abc.com/path/to/module/stream [build failed]
?       a.abc.com/path/to/module/stream/reg   [no test files]
FAIL    a.abc.com/path/to/module/weighted [build failed]
```

I'm using go version 1.15.6

Is there any way to find the reason for the build failure?

Comment: What is the package, is it only tests and which version of Go? Could it be related to this github issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27333

Comment: I'm using go version 1.15.6. The above issues is raised for test only packages. But in this case, I keep test files under the parent package that I'm testing.

Comment: What's the full output of the command you are running?

Comment: @Christian Added the output to the question

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to find the reason for the build failure?

Build (or test) the package individually.

Comment: Is there a way to do that for all packages?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer, but I was having a similar issue and perhaps my process can help you solve your problem.

First, `go help` is your friend. The Go documentation, reference, and just Go in general is about making you *productive*. So the Go team puts a lot of effort into explaining things well.

`go help test` is a good place to start to get info about flags, but it doesn't list `-coverpkg`. It does however point to `go help testflag`:

> The test binary also accepts flags that control execution of the test; these
> flags are also accessible by 'go test'. See 'go help testflag' for details.

`go help testflag` has this to say about `-coverpkg`:

```
-coverpkg pattern1,pattern2,pattern3
    Apply coverage analysis in each test to packages matching the patterns.
    The default is for each test to analyze only the package being tested.
    See 'go help packages' for a description of package patterns.
    Sets -cover.
```

Emphasis on "***The default is for each test to analyze only the package being tested,***" Meaning if I depend on a package `init()` function I might have issues if I am working package by package.

If you want to follow the advice of running each package individually with `coverpkg` you can use `go list ./...` in your module's root directory to a get a list of all your packages and then use some shell scripting to iterate through them.

Ultimately, in my case I deduced that `-coverpkg` was testing each package one by one and therefore probably *loading* packages one by one. So I was able to narrow down my issue to a package's `init()` function. No idea why it was causing the problem, but moving a few lines out of the `init()` function that could go into the `main()` function fixed my issue.

(I was also lucky that the error message was easy to google and I knew it had something to do with CLI flag parsing. See [*Using kingpin in test files*](https://github.com/alecthomas/kingpin/issues/187))